# Kile creates special character in empty cells for tables

Tags: tables, unicode, kile

I am using Kile as a Latex editor, and I particularly like the Tabular Wizard. However, when a cell has an empty value, Kile adds a special character, a pink `×`.

When I try to compile the document into pdf format, I then have errors because this special character that supposedly represents empty cells is not known in UTF-8.

Currently I am replacing the special characters with white spaces, but I believe this solution is flimsy at best.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of those markers is to be able to move easily from cell to cell, which you can do with Edit --> Bullet --> Next/previous bullet. The default keyboard shortcuts are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>

But if you don't need these markers:
In the bottom left of the wizard window there is a checkbox for **Insert bullet**. Uncheck this, and Kile will not insert them.

[image]

Comment: @Torbjørn T., what is your OS?

Comment: @Sigur Kubuntu.